# Complexity analysis of a polynomial and a logarithmic exponential function

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I need to find the asymptotic relationship between the functions $f(n) = n^{100}$ and $g(n) = (log_2n)^{(1/2) \cdot log_2n}$.

I did the following to show that $f(n) = O(g(n))$:

$n^{100} \leq (log_2n)^{(1/2) \cdot log_2n} \impliedby 2^{n^{100}} \leq  2^{(log_2n)^{(1/2) \cdot {log_2n}}} \impliedby 2^{100 \cdot n} \leq n^{(1/2) \cdot log_2n} \impliedby 2^{2^{100 \cdot n}} \leq 2^{n^{(1/2) \cdot log_2n}} \impliedby 2^{200 \cdot n} \leq 2^{n \cdot (1/2) \cdot log_2n} \impliedby 200 \cdot n \leq (1/2) \cdot n \cdot log_2n \impliedby 200 \leq (1/2) \cdot log_2n \impliedby 400 \leq log_2n \impliedby n \geq 2^{400}$

However, my analysis seems to be incorrect, because when i plug the relevant numbers (some $n \geq 2^{400}$ into WolframAlpha, the inequality doesn't hold. I believe that I'm using some exponent properties wrong in my calculations, but I'm unable to spot them. Could you please elaborate on what part am I missing?

Thank you very much

Comment: Who writes implications right-to-left in the middle of a bunch of left-to-right text?

Comment: I did it because on paper, I made an assumption that is the leftmost inequality in the implication chain, and then worked my way from there. I couldn't have known how big the n should be beforehand. Should I write it as you suggested to make it more clear?

Comment: Implication chains really should read in the order of the implications.  (This aids the reader in understanding.  The reader doesn't need to know *how* you got your result, just what your result is, presented in a way that makes parsing it straightforward.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go from $2^{200 \cdot n} \leq 2^{n \cdot (1/2) \cdot \log_2 n}$ to $2^{100 \cdot n} \leq 2^{(1/2) \log_2 n}$ via an intermediate step.  This can't be right as you have taken the square root of the left-hand side and the $n^\text{th}$ root of the right-hand side.

Perhaps more useful is this identity $$
    a^b = (a)^b = (\mathrm{e}^{\ln a})^b = \mathrm{e}^{b \ln a} \text{.}
$$ Using this on your original complicated function, I get $$
    (\log_2 n)^{(1/2) \log_2 n} = \mathrm{e}^{(1/2) \log_2 n \log_2 \log_2 n} = n^{(1/2) \log_2 \log_2 n} \text{,}
$$ which should help you with your asymptotic analysis and help you realize that $2^{400}$ might not be big enough to see the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still having trouble understanding what is wrong with my reasoning. I used the rule that 2^(200*n) = 2^(2^100n) and the same rule for the right hand side, and then just got rid of the exponent basis, since both side had the same exponent basis 2. Notice that you made a mistake, I don't go to 2^((1/2) * logn), but to n^((1/2) * logn).

Comment: @abc : Is that rule even true for $n=1$?

Comment: Oh, it seems not to be :/ But isn't it just the exponent power rule : http://www.rapidtables.com/math/number/exponent.htm#power ? It's getting late here, I must be missing something very trivial.

Comment: @abc : It's better to think of exponential identities with the question: "How many "$2$"s does this side say to multiply together and how many does that side?"

Comment: @abc : $(2^a)^b \neq 2^{(a^b)}$.  The first one says "$a$ many $2$s, repeated $b$ times" (which is $a \times b$ many "$2$"s).  The second one says "$a^b$ many $2$s", which is clearly not the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I realized my mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Write for convenience $\exp_2(x)=2^x$.  We have $a^z=(2^{\log_2 a})^z=\exp_2(z\log_2 a)$, hence $(\log_2 n)^{(1/2)\log_2 n}=\exp_2({1\over 2}\log_2 n\cdot \log_2 \log_2 n)$, whereas $n^{100}=$ $\exp_2(100\log_2 n)$.  We have $100\log_2 n=o(\log_2 n\cdot \log_2\log_2 n)$, and therefore $n^{100}=\exp_2(100\log_2 n) =$ $o(\exp_2({1\over2}\log_2 n\cdot \log_2\log_2 n))$ $=o((\log_2 n)^{(1/2)\log_2 n}).$  This solves your problem.

As to what you did wrong, I don't quite see how $2^{200n} \leq 2^{n (1/2) \log_2n}$ implies $2^{2^{100n}} \leq 2^{n^{(1/2) \log_2n}}$.  If we raise $2$ to the square root of the left hand side, we get $2^{2^{100n}}$; if we raise $2$ to the square root of the right hand side, we get $2^{2^{n(1/4)\log_2 n}}$, and that seems to be $2^{n^{n/4}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I still don't quite understand what am I doing wrong. The implication comes from the fact that I can put the inequalities as the exponent of 2, as I have done, and the inequality should still hold. for example, if I have 2 < 3, then 5^2 < 5^3. And if I have 5^2^3, its the same as 5^(2*3) = 5^6.

Comment: $5^{2^3}=5^8$, whereas $(5^2)^3 = 5^{2\cdot 3}=5^6$ as you say.  Those values, $5^{2^3}$ versus $(5^2)^3$, differ by a factor $5^2=25$.  I do agree that if $a<b$ then $2^a<2^b$ for real $a,b$.

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now :)

Answer (score 0):

$\log_2 f(n)=100 \log_2 n$ while $\log_2 g(n)=(1/2)(\log_2 n) \log_2 (\log_2 n)$ so for $n>2$ we have $$1-\frac {\log_2 f(n)}{\log_2 g(n)}=1-\frac {200}{ \log_2 (\log_2 n)}$$ which $\to 1$ as $n\to \infty.$

We have $f(n)=$o$(g(n))$, and, a fortiori, $f(n)=$O$(g(n)$),  because  $$\log_2f(n)/g(n)=\log_2 f(n)-\log _2g(n)=[-\log g_2(n)]\cdot [1-\frac {\log_2 f(n)}{\log_2 g(n)}\;]$$ which goes to $-\infty$ as $n\to \infty$ (because $-\log_2 g(n)\to -\infty$ and the other term $\to 1).$

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious why do you subtract from 1 at all? Can't you just take the limit of the division, which goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, which by definition means that f(n) = o(g(n)). And since f(n) = o(g(n)), then it must be true that f(n) = O(g(n)) also?

Comment: It just  made the last sentence simpler ,( but you are right.) A proof is easier to digest when the parts in the conclusion are pre-cooked.  Re big O and small o, yes, directly from the def'ns. "A fortiori" is Latin for "from the stronger."